# Scroller contentInset issues in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, indicator

I would want to know how to propertly set an Scroller in a NavigationController child.

Hi, in advantage I'll appreciate any help. (Since I can't post images, I'll upload them to dropbox and place them in a Folder)

[Dropbox Folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i9lyey4982wgqtw/AACRrgNNwqJ9RGWi1zI9oCzoa?dl=0)

The app is iPad in Portrait. I have a scroller in the third view of a NavigationController.The scroller is placed to fit the view with the Nav. Bar `( 0, 44, 768, 980)`

In the Interface Builder I placed a button just below the Navigation Bar and other one in the bottom of the view

(**Xcode Interface Builder.png** in Dropbox folder)

But when I run the app, all the content is moved down and the scroll indicator doesn't get to the top (The content goes upper than the indicator)

(**Scroller do not get to the top.png** in Dropbox folder)

(**iOS Simulator 1.png** in Dropbox folder)

I tried the `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

But the top gets cutted

(**iOS Simulator 2.png** in Dropbox folder)

Also I noticed that in iOS Simulator 1, the content scrolls more than the size I setted with
[scroller setContentSize:]

What can I do to make things right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: The top stills get cutted. I can simply Down the button a little bit. But the problem is if I use `[_scroller setContentOffset:` To get to the top, it scrolls too much.

The "solution" I found is subtract 20 points in the top of the scroll view (Not moving it down), in the Interface Builder. Like this:
[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/doibd1ytu7hhjex/Final%20Solution.png?dl=0)  I hope Apple fix this

Comment: Also with `self.automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInstets = NO;`